# Swift Check if computer is asleep

Tags: swift, macos

I have a Mac OSX program that has to remain on the top of every application, but when I put the computer to sleep it appears on top of the user sign in page of the computer it shows it above that. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this application running as root or something? It seems to me that it shouldn't be possible for an application running in userspace to appear above the login screen, and if this is occurring, you should send a Radar report to Apple along with some sample code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I use a method that uses a timer that sets it above all other applications.

Comment: view.window?.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel()) + 1

Comment: Well if the computer is set to go to sleep after a time period of being inactive and they wake it up with the program open it will pop up over the sign in page